# android linespacing not working

Tags: android, textview

I have customized `list view` which contains `Text view` with custom Arabic font.

I tried to set Line spacing using below **code**:

```
 qArabic.setLineSpacing(25, (float)2);
```

above code sets line spacing only for first line, from second line onward line    spacing not working.

Comment: Mind posting the text contents of the textview? Are there any other styles applied to them (bold/enlarge etc)? Is the textview word wrapped or are the lines explicit? (eg \n)?

Comment: No it was the issue with font, i edited font with fond forge,  There was a problem in font metrics, Win Ascent, Win Descent etc  http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=22374

Answer (score 1):

There was issue with font, I edited font metric details using fontforge,

Here is the link how to edit font line space details

http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=22374